# How to work oke-ish with typing using Pyspark?

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, jvm

Given that PySpark connects to a java virtual machine and calls functions in that, the possibility of working with '[typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)' from PyPi (PEP 484) falls short.

Example:

```
    @property
    def hadoop_configuration(self):
        return self._client.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()  # type: ignore
 
    @property
    def filesystem_path_func(self) -> Callable[[str], Any]:
        return self._client.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path  # type: ignore
 
    @property
    def filesystem_path(self):
        return self.filesystem_path_func(self.path)
 
    @property
    def filesystem(self):
        return self.filesystem_path_func(self.path).getFileSystem(self.hadoop_configuration)  # type: ignore
```

I'm trying to use the hadoop filesystem inside the following function.

```
SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

The 'self._client' is part of the SparkAsset class, but it's basically constructed using this.

```
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().sparkContext._jvm
```

Do you have any ideas on what to use? Thanks!

Comment: What does `oke-ish` mean? This thread is the top Google search result for the phrase.